# .net Graph Mining

Tags: .net, graph, architecture, mining

Briefly, I need some advice on a solution that I’m trying to implement. 
I'm implementing a social network, using .net technologies and I need to infer knowledge from the data collected and persisted at the database (A kind of Graph/Link Mining). 
My questions are:

1. This task should be performed by a business intelligence tool?
2. Do you know any .net framework to process this type of information (graphs)?
3. How should I persist the result data? Using a separate database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a BI expert but yes this does sound like a BI tool could be useful.

I don't know of any .Net library, but [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) is usually a good place to look if you're after something open source.

Using a separate database is definitely a good idea if you want to do lots of reporting and the Transactional part of the application is usually busy.  FYI transactional databases are usually known as [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) where-as databases intended for reporting are usually classified as [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP); the Wikipedia links give a fairly good introduction if the terms are new to you.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. Transactional data should be isolated from big querys.

Answer (score 0):

if you need automatic inference support you might take a look at Semantic Web solutions  http://www.rdfabout.net/intro/? like http://www.dotnetrdf.org/ which provide access to a lot of RDF stores (RDF databases).

Pure graph databases or graph2SQL mappers seldom provide an out-of-the box inference support.

Cheers,
 Achim